# Indexing of hash-value column vs INT IDs for session tokens

Tags: performance, index, mariadb, authentication, session

Let's say:

- your application should use session IDs generated with a CSPRNG, which shall authenticate your user sessions
- your system uses PHP 8.2 and MariaDB 10.6

Which of the approaches below performs better:

Approach A (Index on hashed session ID):

- the PK column of your sessions table is the one which holds the output of PHP's `password_hash` function, applied to a value generated via a CSPRNG.
- upon every incoming request, you hash the session ID delivered by the client, and query the DB by that hash.

Approach B (Index on decrypted INT session ID):

- the PK column of your sessions table is a simple integer, which is encrypted before being delivered to your client.
- upon every incoming request, you decrypt the session ID delivered by the client.
- if the decryption fails, someone tampered with the token --> return 401
- if the decryption succeeds, you query by the accordingly obtained session ID.

Is the performance hit you get from indexing hashes vs INTs negligible in such a case?
I personally also like the fact that approach B provides a way to verify if someone tampered with the token, and avoids the DB-roundtrip if so. Do you see an approach to do so using hashes, as in approach A?

**UPDATE**

So let's say you have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE sessdata (
  sid_hash BINARY(60) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  sdata JSON NOT NULL
);
```

With this, the simple insertion and subsequent attempted retrieval via hash using PHP and PDO fails:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    dsn     : "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8mb4",
    username: $db_user,
    password: $db_p,
    options : [
                  // Throw PDO Exception in case of any error
                  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                  // Fetch the obtained result as associative array by default
                  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
              ]
);

$raw_binary_sid = random_bytes(32);

$hash = password_hash(
    password: $raw_binary_sid,
    algo    : PASSWORD_DEFAULT
);

// Keep this somewhere in your storage
$base64_urlsafe_nopadding = sodium_bin2base64(
    string: $raw_binary_sid,
    id    : SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_URLSAFE_NO_PADDING
);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO sessdata (sid_hash,sdata) VALUES (:hash,JSON_ARRAY())");

$stmt->execute(
    [
        'hash' => $hash
    ]
);

// Then in a separate PHP Session try to retrieve it, doesnt work 

$hash = password_hash(
    password: sodium_base642bin(
                  $base64_urlsafe_nopadding,
                  SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_URLSAFE_NO_PADDING
              ),
    algo    : PASSWORD_DEFAULT
);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sessdata WHERE sid_hash = :hash");

$stmt->execute(
    [
        'hash' => $hash
    ]
);

$stmt->fetchAll(); // empty array = no records found
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 2**

Okay got the problem. PDO by default binds parameter to a query using the `PDO::PARAM_STR` data type / string data type. If I bind the parameter as `PDO::PARAM_LOB` data type instead during the insert and select operations, it all works.

So in the end there are two final questions:

1. Is it correct that queries using the above-mentioned code will perform much faster than if I would index the hash column with the `VARCHAR(60)` data type?
2. Are truncated inserts impossible; e.g. will the 60-character long strings generated in PHP via `password_hash('password',PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` always match exactly the length specified via `BINARY(60)` ? Or is it wiser to use `VARBINARY(60)` to avoid danger of eventually padded / truncated values?

Comment: What is a "session ID" and why it it even in the running?

Comment: By session ID I mean the ID of a session, after logging in a user with success on a login system. I use it to have some kind of selector for the session DB table records, a custom table which holds session data per sctive session and relates it to the according session ID. With every request, the session must be authenticated and its data retrieved, and the first step in doing so is retrieving the according session data record via some kind of ID. Hence the lookup should be fast and the indexing ideal.

Comment: …and the session ID itself should be hard to guess and cryptographically secure, sth like what you get when using random_bytes() in PHP.

Comment: How about `UUID()`?

Comment: The main question I have is not really about the generation itself, but about how to index a column in mariadb whose value is a hash, and if that even is a common approach..?

Comment: How long is a session ID?  Does it have any properties, such as being chronologically increasing values?

Comment: I'd say sth in between 128 - 256 bits, and no, the goal is that they're completely random and unguessable hashes, so there's no logical order or similar. Would you use a simple BTREE index on a varchar column for this, being the PK column of the sessions data table?

Comment: `INT` has only 32 bits; `BIGINT` only 64.  256 bits needs `BINARY(32)` or `hex in `VARCHAR(64)` or `VARCHAR(42) for "Base64".

Comment: I feel you misunderstood my question. It‘s the length of the session ID which is around 128 bits (see [OWASPs cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html)) but the ID itself is not stored in the DB, but its hash. My question thus is, how would you type and index a column in MariaDB with values e.g. generated via password_hash(random_bytes(16)) ? The PHP Docs tell that password_hash generates 255 characters outputs, but whats the ideal index and data type youd use, also for max lookup performance?

Comment: Edit for simplification, let's assume you call `password_hash(random_bytes(16),PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`, which generates a 60-characters long string output. Which data type and index would you ideally use for maximum lookup performance (and hash integrity and -uniqueness / low collision chance)? A `PK` column of type `BINARY(60)` ? Or rather `CHAR(60)` with a case-sensitive collation like `utf8_bin`?

Comment: And by 'maximum lookup performance' I just mean that the query to the session data table with the `WHERE` condition being `WHERE session_id_hash = 'hashvalue'` should be as performant as possible.

Answer (score 1):

- For keys (especially including the `PRIMARY KEY`) shorter is better.  Two reasons: faster comparison, and smaller disk footprint.
- For `JOINs`, `WHERE`, and `ORDER BY`, `INT` or `BINARY` is fastest for comparing and sorting; a `_bin` collation may be identical to `BINARY`; other collations vary depending on both charset and collation.
- "Locality of reference" is beneficial in huge datasets.  This is where rows being fetch (either in a single in query or in multiple queries) benefit from the keys being "close".  Good case:  `WHERE x BETWEEN ... AND ...`.  Worst:  The column is any kind of hash.

For small tables and small Joins, etc, none of the above matters much.

Most of a query's time is spent in network transmission, query parsing, row parsing, result building, etc.  It is rare for your concerns to impact a query's time by more tina 10%.

Comment: Meaning for a PK column holding values generated with `password_hash(random_bytes(16),PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`, you would set the data type of that column to be `BINARY(60)`, correct?

Comment: Please check my example above, I'm having issues with the `BINARY` data type.

Comment: Usually a function returns hex, then UNHEX() is needed to turn it into BINARY:   `INSERT INTO foo (key) VALUES (UNHEX(...))`

Comment: Nope I guess the problem here is that `password_hash` actually generates a random salt used to do the hashing upon every call. Meaning the above-written example fails as soon as I'll try to insert and retrieve the hash in two distinct PHP processes (e.g. call `password_hash()` twice with the same password), as the generated hashes will be different, no matter if you provide exactly the same password. That's the reason why I'm getting no query results. Is there any hash method you recommend in PHP / MariaDB which does not use salts?

Comment: I like to use MD5(...) (plus UNHEX):  `SELECT MD5('a'), MD5(123);` -->  0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661 , 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

Comment: Note:  MD5 is a trapdoor -- You cannot retrieve the original string from the hash.  If you need to retrieve the original string, see AES_*

Comment: Hmmm AFAIK, md5 is [not really recommended for password / token storage](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure). Ugh after all of this, I think I'll just use an auto incrementing INT PK in the session data table, do `password_hash()`, and concatenate the PK of the generated DB record with the generated session token when delivering the token to the client. Then simply detach them from each other upon authentication, query by the provided pk, and verify the hash.